# How to delete items from recyclerview after 3 days automatically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to delete all items older than 3 days in recyclerview. I am adding recyclerview dynamically, 
So how can we delete item rows from recyclerview after 3 days automatically ?

Comment: What did you try so far? Show some codes.

Comment: first I have inserted rows in sqlite and then I loaded on recycler view. I want to delete rows after 3 days from recycler view not from sqlite db

Comment: This can be done with many logics like - You can insert time with your data and can check that if the inserted time completed 3 hours then you can delete this item  before creating recyclerView or etc.

Comment: Your question is about deleting rows from SQLite database after 3 days. You can check the row insert date and current date when user starts the app.

Comment: Thanks, this might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save each date when you fill your recyclerView, maybe in a SQLite database, after that, you can check that register in onCreate() method of your activity, and add a condition (if has passed three days), if true, just refill it like this:

```
     mRecyclerAdapter = new mRecyclerAdapter(yourItemList);
     mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
     mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After this, overwrite the date of your register in SQLite and that´s all, should work well,

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks , I will try

Comment: Is it not simple to fetch only items which are not older than 3 sweets in db

Comment: @war_Hero of course it is. find out the current day. look for any objects with the day over 3 days, remove that object. pretty str8 forward. You have to make sure you keep an object of date though.